# Function keeps repeating in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

My code is written in a file "plot.m".

If I put the following code in "plot.m", when I call plot("20%"), the Octave GUI will keep opening a new window with a new figure indefinitely.

```
function X = plot(folderName)

X = 0;

data =  ([folderName, "\\summary.txt"]);
NUM_SURVIVED = data(1);
NUM_DATA = size(data)(1)-1;
FINAL_WEALTH = data(2 : NUM_DATA);

%plot FINAL_WEALTH

figure;
plot(1:numel(FINAL_WEALTH), FINAL_WEALTH, '-b', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('FINAL_WEALTH');

end
```

However, if I put the following code in "plot.m" and run it, the program works as intended and will plot data from "summary.txt".

```
data =  ("20%\\summary.txt");
NUM_SURVIVED = data(1);
NUM_DATA = size(data)(1)-1;
FINAL_WEALTH = data(2 : NUM_DATA);

%plot FINAL_WEALTH

figure;
plot(1:numel(FINAL_WEALTH), FINAL_WEALTH, '-b', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('FINAL_WEALTH');
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong in the first section of code? I would like to write it as a function so that I can call it multiple times for different folder names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `plot` from the function `plot`, you get endless recursion. Rename your function and its file.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to Michael's answer, if you *really* wanted to name your function as *"plot"* and override the built-in `plot` function, but *still* wanted to be able to call the *built-in* `plot` function inside it, this is actually possible to do by using the [`builtin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Overloading-and-Autoloading.html) function to call the built-in version of `plot`. Your code would then look like this:

```
function X = plot (folderName)

  % same code as before

  figure;
  builtin ("plot", 1:numel(FINAL_WEALTH), FINAL_WEALTH, '-b', 'LineWidth', 2);
  xlabel ('x');
  ylabel ('FINAL_WEALTH');

end
```

Obviously, whether it's a good idea to overload such a core function in the first place is an entirely different discussion topic. (Hint: don't!)

Comment: +. I didn't know about `builtin`. But make it sure to never ever overload the `builtin` function. Pun isn't intended.

Comment: ahahah, ikr? that's just asking for it! xD